# adding key to .open method for api

Tags: ajax, api

So I'm learning `ajax` and in my practice I'm getting "**missing mashape app key**" error when I run the following code.
I have the right `key` and `url`, however I am not sure about the `.open` method.

I know how to do `.getjson` method, but for learning purposes I want to try pure javascript instead of using the `jquery` version.

I tried googling everywhere, but can't seem to find info on how to inserts keys.

```js
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload=function(){


    responseObject=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   console.log(responseObject); 
  };
    xhr.open('GET','https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/',{"mashape-key": "4Aa7D7LmkqmshukJOKpCSuADwcpEp1jv8cWjsnUdliFYFkwPsS"},true);
    xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured answer out. You can set .setRequestHeader right after .open with the api key. So for example see below.

If there is another way to implement in .open, would like to know as well.

```js
xhr.open('GET','https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Key", "fjZoisqRfomshkDSNH1AZLpFCS6gp1yVxU8jsn3fPleq6TIPeF")
```